# PHP Includes function, not displaying images

Tags: php, css

This is all that is contained on my home.php page

```
<?php
    include ('../bgs/bg-verbier.html');
    include('../menus/menu-verbier.html');
?>
```

both of the requested pages lie in the parent directory. The /menus/menu-verbier.html has posed no problem from the include function, however the '../bgs/bg-verbier.html is. The file as been found however the images aren't displaying.

The path of the images is working on a .php page that lies in the same parent directory,

Here's the ../bgs/bg-verbier.html' file:

```
<div id="bg">
    <b><i><i><img src="images/verbier/0.jpg"></i></i></b>
    <!--b:holder, i#1: large canvas, i#2: center verticaly -->
    <b><i><i><img src="images/verbier/1.jpg"></i></i></b>
    <b><i><i><img src="images/verbier/2.jpg"></i></i></b>
    <b><i><i><img src="images/verbier/3.jpg"></i></i></b>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scaler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/example.js"></script>
```

Comment: the pathes given in the images are not absolute. And by the include you import them into your "current" location and thus the browser cant find them

Comment: Your formatting in your code example seems to have issues

Comment: Why do you have images wrapped in bold and (double'd up) italic tags? Also your images should include `alt` attributes for browsers which do not display images.

Comment: Check the path to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `include` a file, it's like if you were to copy & paste that file's contents into the PHP file.

So, it's like the PHP file is asking for `images/verbier/0.jpg`, which means it's looking in the same folder as the PHP file.

I suggest you edit the HTML file so it uses absolute paths to the images, like:

```
<img src="/menus/images/verbier/0.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `images` folder must be in the same directory as the `php` file that is calling it. Otherwise, you must specify the relative path to the images folder.